# android volley sending array list to php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, sqlite, android-volley

I am working with volley library and I have succeeded in sending single parameters to the PHP script but when it comes to sending an array/list of arrays.

My android application is a user form to create an  order of medicine items which is to be sent to server for processing.

I tended to store the user input into an sqlite database continuously  until the users presses the submit button where the application should retrieve the transaction from sqlite db as a table or array of string arrays and send the request to PHP script to store that values in an MySQL db .

I know how to transfer sqlite data to php  ,

I would appreciate any help that will get me started.

Thanks in advance